# unfortunately API demo has stopped

Tags: android

I have created an app using eclipse. Here I have posted the manifest file  and the console.
I can see my app on my emulator, but when I open my app it shows unfortunately API demo has stopped.my log cat is free.

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.navigate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.navigate.SecondScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>

       </activity>

     </application>

</manifest>
```

//console

```
[2014-02-02 17:12:14 - Navigate] Android Launch!
[2014-02-02 17:12:14 - Navigate] adb is running normally.
[2014-02-02 17:12:14 - Navigate] Performing com.example.navigate.SecondScreenActivity activity launch
[2014-02-02 17:12:14 - Navigate] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'androidhelloworld'
[2014-02-02 17:12:14 - Navigate] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'androidhelloworld'
[2014-02-02 17:12:42 - Navigate] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-02-02 17:12:42 - Navigate] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-02-02 17:14:01 - Navigate] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-02-02 17:14:01 - Navigate] Uploading Navigate.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-02-02 17:14:02 - Navigate] Installing Navigate.apk...
[2014-02-02 17:14:59 - Navigate] Success!
[2014-02-02 17:15:00 - Navigate] Starting activity com.example.navigate.SecondScreenActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-02-02 17:15:03 - Navigate] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.navigate/.SecondScreenActivity }
```

Comment: That's not the Logcat Trace..

Comment: What you claim is the "log cat" is the Eclipse Console. There is a separate LogCat view in Eclipse. It will contain a stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: sorry. what i have posted is console. Not a log cat. my log cat is error free.

Answer (score 0):

for me i also face the same problem, when emulator is start, will show the message unfortunately API demo has stopped. try go to system settings > apps> uninstall the API demo apps . hope this might help you ~

Answer (score 0):

Try Uninstalling the API Demos App. It will surely help.